# MDX drillthrough not working with subselects

Tags: ssas, mdx

I don't have much experience with MDX and Analysis Services. I am trying to do a drillthrough and for the most part I got it right. However, there is one example that I can't figure out. When I'm using a subselect and a crossjoin the result of the drillthrough is incorrect. I ran the same query without the drillthrough clause and the result is correct. Somehow the drillthrough statement is collecting all data ignoring the subselect result. What I'm doing wrong?

The MDX query is:

```
DRILLTHROUGH 
SELECT NON EMPTY (([Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2016]) * {[Measures].[Amount]}) ON COLUMNS 
FROM (SELECT ( {[Accounts].[Account Id].&[xxxx]} ) ON COLUMNS
      FROM [ExampleDW])
```

Answer (score 0):

A sub-select isn't a normal filter can you not just re-write you script using a true filter - the `WHERE` clause :

```
DRILLTHROUGH 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
   [Dates].[Calendar Year].&[2016]) 
*  [Measures].[Amount] ON COLUMNS 
FROM [ExampleDW]
WHERE [Accounts].[Account Id].&[xxxx];
```